# Aceso a ficheros de carpetas en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xml, hosting

Muy buenas a todos,

He creado un wordpress y he creado una carpeta adicional para meter ficheros xml, pero no puedo acceder a ellos.

Es decir, en mi web "www.webejemplo.com", he creado una carpeta llamada "ficheros" con un fichero llamado "info.xml". Cuando intento acceder a un navegador a "www.webejemplo.com/ficheros/info.xml" no se carga y salta error de wordpress. ¿Alguna manera de evitar esto sin modificar el link?

Muchas gracias

Edito: La carpeta se encuentra en el directorio raiz, junto las carpetas wp-admin y demás. En el htaccess están implementados las siguientes normas:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Por defecto, el wordpress permite el acceso a los archivos directamente mediante las rules rewrite del archivo .htaccess.  Revisa a ver si las tienes y son correctas. Asegúrate que tienes esta: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` y esta otra `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` antes de la que carga el index.php del wordpress, que seria esta: `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`.  Si esas rules son correctas entonces el problema esta en que la carpeta que dices o el archivo estan mal escritos o mal colocados en tu ruta de tu web.

Comment: @masterguru las linas en el httaccess se encuentran, fue lo primero que hice. Lo único que cambia es que en el rewriterule no viene el parametro qsa, ya que si lo pongo me da error 500 ¿puede tener que ver?  La carpeta que he creado se encuentra en el directorio raiz al mismo nivel que wp-content y demás

Comment: Pues solo te queda comprobar permisos de esas carpetas. Mira si comparten el mismo owner/group que los demas archivos y carpetas del wordpress y si tienen los permimos de escritura/lectura bien puestos (yo siempre pongo 755 a las carpetas y 644 a los archivos y no me dan problemas, pero eso ya dependera de como estes ejecutando apache)

Comment: efectivamente @masterguru

Comment: ¿El "efectivamente" que quiere decir? ¿que está arreglado? ¿o que me das la razón en lo que digo pero sigues con el problema?